# Restart value each year

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement a method in which I want to reset a value everytime the new year comes.
In general, this value increments on each insert of a new row in the database, but when the year comes, this value has to reset and start again from 1.

I have tried to do this with this piece of code and I cannot go any further.

```
public async Task<myTable> InsertNewRow(myTable entity) 
{
    DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Today;
    var myDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2024");

    myTable mt = new()
    {
        name = entity.name,
        lastname = entity.lastname,
        restartValue = todaysDate == myDate ? ID : 1; //because since ID is primary key and has auto_increment     attribute, I thought this was the easiest way to increment the restartValue as well.
    };
    _context.myTable.Add(mt);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Create a new table with only one record which will contain a DateTime. Fetch this value whenever you need it and compare it to todays date perhaps? If it's a new year, then proceed to reset your value but also, dont forget to update the DateTime in your database as well.

Comment: You have to load the last inserted value from database into your client. Then compare current year with last entry year. If it changed, set counter to zero, otherwise take counter from last entry and increment by one. Be aware, that this approach can't be parallelized and must be serialized by using some lock mechanism if this could be an issue.

Comment: in transaction: get max of this field for year and add one then apply value to new row

Comment: AFAIK a transaction ensures that all actions within it are applied _atomic_. But it doesn't prevent multiple transactions in parallel which would read the same value.

Comment: I would question the premise of this question in the first place. Why do you need this in the database? You can calculate all this on the fly.

Comment: I'd second DavidG: don't. It will become a recurring point of error.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is the value is always either 0 or 1 but it would be better if you told us what your actual problem is

Comment: Add a sequence to the database and schedule a job that resets it each 1/1 at 00:00. Set a default constraint in the incrementing field that draws the next value from this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the latest data in the db and then you can decide what to actually do for the new data. you need a extra column for the year. That's better for both control and reporting